# Succinct/concise syntax for 'optional' object keys in ES6/ES7?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016, ecmascript-next

There are already a lot of [cool features](https://devhints.io/es6) in ES6/ES7 for defining Javascript objects. However, the following pattern is common in Javascript:

```js
const obj = { 
  requiredKey1: ..., 
  requiredKey2: ... 
};

if (someCondition) { 
  obj.optionalKey1 = ...;
}
```

Is there a way to define the object all at once with both optional and required keys?

Comment: Why not just use a ternary? `optionKey1: someCondition ? value : undefined`?

Comment: @FelixKling I think that's a largely theoretical distinction because there is not a 'whole' ES6 or ES7 standard implemented in Node/browser environments and most people are using transpilers anyway.

Comment: Well, it defines the scope for answers. We don’t know what  you are using. Also I don’t want people to misuse the term ES7 for experimental features.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm asking about any standard of Ecmascript; obviously existing supported standards is better. If this can be done with experimental features, okay. If it can be done with ES6 or ES7, better. If it is possible with ES5, super!

Comment: I would love to see something like `{ key?: optionalValue }` or with property
shorthand: `{ optionalValue? }`

Answer (score 309, accepted):

You can use [object spread](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) to have an optional property:

```js
let flag1 = true;
let flag2 = false;

// extra cases added by Abdull
let optionalKey8 = 8;
let optionalKey9 = undefined;
let optionalKey10 = false;
let optionalKey11 = null;
let optionalKey12 = "twelve";

const obj = { 
  requiredKey1: 1, 
  requiredKey2: 2,
  ...(flag1 && { optionalKey3: 3 }),
  ...(flag2 && { optionalKey4: 4, optionalKey5: 5 }),  // ignored
  ...(flag1 && { optionalKey6: 6, optionalKey7: 7 }),
  ...(optionalKey8 && { optionalKey8 }),
  ...(optionalKey9 && { optionalKey9 }), // ignored
  ...(optionalKey10 && { optionalKey10 }), // ignored
  ...(optionalKey11 && { optionalKey11 }), // ignored
  ...(optionalKey12 && { optionalKey12 })
};

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Note: this will make turn any getters into static values.

Comment: As a note, you don't need the parentheses.  eg. `...flag1 && { optionalKey1: 5 },` is fine too.

Comment: @RyanKing can you give a sample ?  ```{get x() {return this.a + this.b}, b: 2, ...a && {a}}``` works as expected

Comment: @zb' `{ ...{ get x() { return 3 } } }`

Comment: @RyanKing ah, optional getter ;) o'c you can't destruct getter ;)

Comment: I receive an error in the false value, I solved with this:
...(flag2 && { optionalKey2: 6, optionalKey3: 7 }) as {},

Comment: sos un capo man.

Comment: lol. Mucho gracias amigo.

Comment: @Abdull - thanks for the edit. I made updates, and mentioned you in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

To indicate `optional` key, you can assign to it `null`, if the condition is false

```js
const someCondition = true;

const obj = { 
  requiredKey1: 1, 
  requiredKey2: 2,
  optionalKey1: someCondition ? 'optional' : null
};

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Good answer, but worth noting that by doing this, `optionalKey1` still appears as one of the keys of the object if the condition is false (and has the value null), whereas OPs original snippet will create an object that lacks the key entirely if the condition is false.

Comment: I think, assigning `null` to the property is more understandable that it is optional and does not have value than checking for the existence

Comment: I personalyl would like to get some sort of error, and generally whatever behavior a language (and JavaScript in particular) would give me when trying to access an inexistent property, rather than making it nullable, since it's *not ever* going to have a value, unlike what nullable values are used for - it it needs to exists, it exists. If it doesn't need to exits, it doesn't - I think that makes more sense.

Comment: @SurenSrapyan adding an *optional* member with `null` value doesn't make it optional. It means that the object has an **actual** member whose assigned value is `null` which actually **is a value**. You may thing that `null` is not a value, but it is. Therefore this doesn't make a member optional. An optional member would be one, that wouldn't be returned by the `Object.entries(obj)` function. If at least you'd assign it a value of `undefined` which would mean that the member is *undefined* and doesn't have a value assigned to it. `Object.entries(obj)` would still see the member though.

Comment: One workaround to fix the optional member with `null` would be removing it in the next line: `Object.keys(obj).forEach((k) => obj[k] == null && delete obj[k]);`
@SurenSrapyan If you add this line, that will make this answer also one of the options.

Answer (score -1):

You can declare the variable by passing it through the below function

```
function removeOptionalKeys(x){
    let obj = {};
    Object.keys(x).forEach((a) => {
        if(x[a]){
            obj[a] = x[a]   
        }
    })
    return(obj)
}
```

Then declare the variable as follows

```
let obj = removeOptionalKeys({
  requiredKey1: 1, 
  requiredKey2: 2,
  optionalKey1: someCondition ? 'optional' : null  
})
```

Comment: That removes all properties with falsy values, which is probably not desired

Answer (score -4):

> the following pattern is common in Javascript

It should not. Having many objects of different shapes can incur a performance penalty. Records should always contain the same keys. So just use

```
const obj = { 
  requiredKey1: …, 
  requiredKey2: …,
  optionalKey1: someCondition ? … : undefined,
};
```

Comment: The pattern is really useful in objects you pass as options.

Comment: @krulik Option object parameters usually can deal totally fine with `undefined` properties, not distinguishing them from non-existing properties.