# How to get only passed key-value pair during destructuring?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have a function which is defined as below

```
  function getProperties({
    url, listName, stage,
  }) {
    return {
      url,
      listName,
      currentStage: stage,
    };
  }
```

If I call this function as

```
getProperties({
  url: '<URL>',
  stage: '<stage>',
})
```

it should return

```
{
  url,
  currentStage: stage,
}
```

So basically I want the function to return only those values which were actually passed as parameter to this function.

Comment: You just need to make couple of checks and return what you *need* to return.

Comment: This becomes tedious job if the arguments list if big.

Comment: What else does this function do? Because if it only returns props (like identity function) then it doesn't make any sense. You can rename one param without such function.

Comment: This is just an example. This function has several such arguments passed. Job of this function is to return the key-value pair with the same/different key name only if the passed object contains the key.

Comment: It's not possible with destructuring. You should have a generic pick function, such as described in https://stackoverflow.com/q/25553910/218196 .

Comment: also possible duplicate of [Succinct/concise syntax for 'optional' object keys in ES6/ES7?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47892127/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `stage` parameter to `currentStage`, assign `[...arguments].pop()` to a local variable if there are `arguments`, else set the variable to a plain object; check if the variable contains `"stage"` property, if the property is defined `delete` the property and set `{currentStage}` as an object to be assigned to the returned object

```js
function getProperties({url, listName, stage: currentStage} = {}) {
  const o = [...arguments].pop() || {};
  return Object.assign(o, "stage" in o ? delete o.stage && {
    currentStage
  } : void 0)
}

console.log(getProperties()); // {}

console.log(getProperties({
  url: "<URL>",
  stage: "<stage>",
})); // {"url": "<URL>", "currentStage": "<stage>"}

console.log(getProperties({listName:"<abc>"})); // {"listName": "<abc>"}
```