# How to optionally initialize object property

Tags: javascript

Is there any approach in JS to initialize a property of an object conditionally? I [can't find](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39376) any information about this yet.

Example: there is a variable, and if it is not `null` or `undefined`, then when initializing the object you are able to add a property with its value **in one line**.

```js
let optionA = "Some option";

const obj = {
   id: 1,
   name: "Object 1",
   ?optionA, // if 'optionA' then add property
}
```

I know only one way: add optional properties after initialization only.

```js
const obj = {
   id: 1,
   name: "Object 1",
}

if (optionA) {
   obj.optionA = optionA;
}
if (optionB) {
   obj.optionA = optionB;
}
if (optionC) {
   obj.optionA = optionC;
}
if (optionD) {
   obj.optionA = optionD;
}
```

As you may have noticed, in this case it is not possible to use a one-line object property shorthand for convenience or a ternary operator, the code becomes bloated.

All I could find is [adding a property with the spread operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47892178) but this looks even worse than `if` statement.

---

I also noticed that this principle is partially implemented in the fetch API:

```js
let optionA;

const req = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    title: 'foo',
    body: 'bar',
    userId: 1,
    optionA,
  }),
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  },
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => console.log(json));

// {title: 'foo', body: 'bar', userId: 1, id: 101}
```

It works with `undefined` only and will log the response without `optionA` property because it will be removed from the body in the request payload.

Comment: _"partially implemented in the fetch API"_ - no, it's just that `JSON.stringify({ foo: undefined }) === '{}'`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you for the link, I've already mentioned it in the question. Unfortunately, it looks worse than simple `if` statement for me.

Comment: *"but this looks even worse than if statement"* - Does it?  It's on one line, integrated into the object initialization syntax, exactly as requested.  It's not clear to me why that doesn't do what you're looking for.

Comment: _"it looks worse than simple `if` statement for me"_ - by all means don't use it, then, but that's still the answer. Note in general the right way to attract additional attention to an existing question (e.g. that you want to see if there are any newer answers to) is a [_bounty_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), not re-posting.

Comment: @David because it's hard to read despite the fact that it is written in one line

Answer (score 1):

You could spread a new object or an empty one, depending on the value ([`==` with `null`/`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality#description)).

```js
const
    a = 0,
    b = 1,
    x = undefined,
    y = null;

console.log({
    ...a == null ? {} : { a },
    ...b == null ? {} : { b },
    ...x == null ? {} : { x },
    ...y == null ? {} : { y }
});
```

Comment: Why this weird `typeof (x ?? noObject) === 'symbol'` instead of just `x == null`?

Comment: @bergi, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the logic from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47892127/succinct-concise-syntax-for-optional-object-keys-in-es6-es7) in a `function` and use that. To me this looks pretty readable and also shows the intent clearly.

I'm not 100% sure if you want the names of the properties preserved, or only their values, so I'm presenting 2 variants.

```
function ifObjHasValue(obj) {
   return Object.values(obj)[0] ? obj : undefined;
}

function ifOptHasValue(option) {
   return option ? { [option]: option } : undefined;
}
```

Demo:

```js
function ifObjHasValue(obj) {
   return Object.values(obj)[0] ? obj : undefined;
}

function ifOptHasValue(option) {
   return option ? { [option]: option } : undefined;
}

let optionA = "", optionB = "Some option", optionC = undefined, optionD = null;

console.log({
  id: 1,
  name: "Object 1",
  ...ifObjHasValue({ optionA }),
  ...ifObjHasValue({ optionB }),
  ...ifObjHasValue({ optionC }),
  ...ifObjHasValue({ optionD })
});

console.log({
  id: 2,
  name: "Object 2",
  ...ifOptHasValue(optionA),
  ...ifOptHasValue(optionB),
  ...ifOptHasValue(optionC),
  ...ifOptHasValue(optionD)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the object shortcut plus `Object.entries()` plus `Array::forEach()` to get an one-liner:

```js
const obj = {
   id: 1,
   name: "Object 1",
}

const optionA = null, optionB = 'optionB', optionC = false;
let optionD;

Object.entries({optionA, optionB, optionC, optionD}).forEach(([k, v]) => v && (obj.optionA = v));

console.log(obj);
```